# Layering fields on top of each other in views

Tags: 6, views

I use Drupal 6 with Views 6.x-2.10.

I have a spotlight region on my page where I want to display a picture and a description of the next upcoming event.

I want the description text to be on top of the image, in a div with half transparent background, sort of `[---image--[description]-]`.
The image and description are fetched with a view. How do I style it so that one field in the view (the description) is on top of the picture field?

It would be easy to do if I could get the content in  `<div class="picture"><div class="description"></div></div>`, but the view puts a hell of a lot of other divs around it, making it impossible to have the description inside of the picture div.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that the easiest and simplest solution is pure css. All you need to know, is the height of the box with text, then it's a simple matter of using `margin-top: -?px;` and creating a background with opacity. One option could be an image.

Comment: Works fine with the addition of a z-index for the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found using `position:relative;` instead of negative margins works more uniform in all browsers, you may want to try this if `margin-top` is giving you some issues in IE.